# Creating a fifth table from four relational tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have these four tables as below. The tables `chat_message_join` and `message` are related through `message_id`. The other two tables are related through `handle_id`:

```
+------------------------+  
| chat_message_join      |  
+------------------------+  
| chat_id                |  
| message_id             |  
+------------------------+  

+------------------------+  
| chat_handle_join       |  
+------------------------+  
| chat_id                |  
| handle_id              |  
+------------------------+

+------------------------+  
| message                |  
+------------------------+  
| message_id             |  
| text                   |  
+------------------------+

+------------------------+  
| handle                 |  
+------------------------+  
| handle_id              |  
| phone                  |  
+------------------------+
```

Now i want to have a fifth table as below,what should be the TSQL statement?

```
+------------------------+  
| flat_message           |  
+------------------------+  
| phone.                 |  
| text                   |  
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: question's goal is not clear. clearly state the purpose of the 5th table like the other two you described.

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan is it?! "Now i want to have a fifth table as below,what should be the TSQL statement?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`into` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql#examples) to create the 5<sup>th</sup> table with the following `select` statement:

```
select     h.phone, 
           m.text
into       flat_message
from       handle h
inner join chat_handle_join chj
        on chj.handle_id = h.handle_id
inner join chat_message_join cmj
        on cmj.chat_id = chj.chat_id
inner join message m
        on m.message_id = cmj.message_id;
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/RFY90977) and [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6008/1).

Comment: What do you mean with "did not work"? Can you provide sample data for your tables and indicate which results are not as expected?

Comment: Can you please provide the error message? It runs without errors [on rextester.com](http://rextester.com/RFY90977). I assume the `tsql` tag is correct of course, or are you not on SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the below point:
Do you want to populate the 5th table for the data from other tables (like only phone and text only in your case)?
or You want to create the 5th table with these 2 fields(phone and text) at runtime ?

for inserting data u can use below:

```
INSERT INTO flat_message
SELECT h.phone, m.text
FROM chat_message_join  as cmj
inner join chat_handle_join as chj on cmj.chat_id = chj.chat_id
inner join message as m  on cmj.messageid = m.messageid
inner join handle as h on h.handleid = chj.handleid
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Focus on gathering the required reputation (50) to place comments.

Comment: @trincot hi why this is not an answer? could you please elaborate.Is only reputation enough to place comment not the knowledge?

Comment: You added to your answer 5 minutes after I wrote the comment. But still you should remove the questions from it. An answer is expected to be that, not a question to the Asker.

Comment: @trincot the query put upon here is not pin point. that's why i asked what actually he wants to do,as simple as that. is there any thing wrong in it?

Comment: Questions to the Asker should be asked in the comments section. (You seem to suggest you asked the questions because of the query you wrote, but actually you did not include the query at first, and only asked questions, which is why I commented).

Comment: @trincot ok. got it. I am new here. Thanks for this.

Comment: this is throwing an error in sqlite3: no such column: h.phone